# От чего / отчего

Tags: орфография

Как правильно? Я думаю, что надо писать *оттого*, т. к. глагол *бояться* употребим с предлогом *из-за (чего-то)*, но не с *от*.

1. «Отчего ты всего боишься? В чём причина кроется-таки?» – «Да оттого я всего боюсь, что меня всё время заставляет бояться, а это – мужчины».
2. «От чего ты всего боишься? В чём причина кроется-таки?» – «Да от того я всего боюсь, что меня всё время заставляет бояться, а это – мужчины».

Comment: Indeed, men are sometimes annoying as flies. You can't hide from them anywhere.

Comment: I do agree! Especially teenagers in their twenties!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правилен такой вариант:

*«**Отчего**  ты всего боишься? В чём причина кроется-таки?» – «Да **оттого** я всего боюсь, что **кто-то** меня всё время заставляет бояться, и это – мужчины".*

1. Это вопросительное местоименное наречие, нет предложного управления и **предметного** значения. Нельзя задать вопрос: ***бояться*** (от кого/чего?) - ***бояться*** от того, кто/что ...
2. Замена ***отчего*** на ***почему*** не гарантирует однозначного решения, например:

*Они, пожалуй, более жизнеспособны. Только вот — **от чего** они защищаются? **От кого** ждут удара?*

*Они, пожалуй, более жизнеспособны. Только вот — **отчего** они защищаются? **Отчего** так боязливы?*

Answer (score 0):

***Отчего ты всего боишься? В чём причина кроется-таки?» – «Да оттого я всего боюсь, что меня всё время заставляет бояться, а это – мужчины***.

*Отчего* можно заменить на *почему*, поэтому слитно.

Пример раздельного:

***От чего эта деталь?***

*Оттого* можно заменить на *потому*, поэтому слитно.

Пример раздельного:

***Я пришел от того человека***.

Фотокарточка с информацией:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По аналогии делается и с *оттого*.